# Give an example of a function $f(x)$ for which $f([-1,1])=(-\infty ,\infty)$

Tags: analysis

A question from *Introduction to Analysis* by Arthur Mattuck:

Give an example of a function $f(x)$ for which $f([-1,1])=(-\infty ,\infty)$.

Since $f$ is defined on a **closed** interval, how can infinity be achieved?

Comment: Something to consider, since $(-\inf,\inf)$ is open, and $[-1,1]$ is closed, no continuous function will satisfy this. Such a function does exist, it is just not continuous.

Comment: @Kutz The interval $\;(-\infty,\,\infty)=\Bbb R\;$ is **also** closed...in fact, the only non-empty one that is both closed and open in the real line under the usual, euclidean topology.

Comment: It is the compactness that matters here, with $f$ continuous $f([-1,1])$ is also compact, which $(-\infty,\infty)$ is not.

Answer (score 4):

Hint. Take a non-continuous function (otherwise $f([-1,1])$ is a bounded and closed interval). For example consider $f(x)=\tan(\pi x/2)$ and extend it at $-1$ and $1$ by setting $f(-1)=a$ and $f(1)=b$ with $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: We can also get more creative and define a map like $f(x)=\frac1x + 1$ for $x<0$, $f(x)=\frac1x - 1$ for $x>0$, and $f(0) \in \mathbb{R}$. I would still say your answer is the most elegant.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot that value of $f$ can be defined at poles at will.

Answer (score 2):

Examples were given with onto functions, but we can even devise a bijection, for instance let consider:

$$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} [-1,1] @>\phi>> ]-1,1[ @>\mathrm{tanh^{-1}}>> \mathbb R \end{CD}$$

The function $\phi$ will take $1$ and $-1$ and send them to inside points, these points in turn will be send to deeper inside points and so on in a cascade of replacements. (*Note: with $0\in \mathbb N$*)

$\phi:\begin{cases} 
\phi(2^{-n})=2^{-(n+1)} & \forall n\in\mathbb N\\
\phi(-2^{-n})=-2^{-(n+1)} & \forall n\in\mathbb N\\
\phi(x)=x & \text{elsewhere}\end{cases}$

The function $\phi$ is bijective but not continuous, while $\tanh^{-1}$ is bijective and continuous on the considered intervals.

If both functions would be continuous then $[-1,1]$ would be sent to $[-\infty,\infty]=\bar{\mathbb R}$ the compactified real set.

You can eventually replace $\tanh(x)$ by $\dfrac x{1+|x|}$ or $\tan(\pi x)$ (or their respective reciprocal) for the same kind of result.